# Button is always in front

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin.Forms application and want to overlap a button with an image:

```
            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                <Image Grid.Column="1"
                       HeightRequest="30"
                       WidthRequest="30">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <FontImageSource
                            Glyph="{StaticResource Reset}"
                            FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                            Color="white" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
```

But in the app the button is always on top

[image]

The icon is correctly rendered as it is visible when I make the button only span on column

[image]

How comes the button is always on the top?

EDIT: Based on the responses I did some testing, since both didn't work for me. It turns out the issue is that I have a scrollviewer as top layout. As soon as I remove that one it works as expected. That would raise the question if that is a bug or if I have to setup the scrollviewer differently?

Example:

```
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid HeightRequest="60" VerticalOptions="Start">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                <Label
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="15,0"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                    Foo
                </Label>

                <Image
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            HeightRequest="30"
            Source="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/6447-200.png"
            WidthRequest="30" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Here is the Result from the original page with and without scrollviewer.

With ScrollViewer:
[image]

Without:

[image]

Xamarin.Forms version: 4.1.0.618606
Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material: 4.1.0.618606

In case the whole layout is interessting, you can find that one on Github too: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox/blob/master/Src/MoneyFox.Presentation/UserControls/ModifyPaymentUserControl.xaml

EDIT2: The issue only occurs on Android. On iOS it acts as expected.

Comment: Post the whole layout code

Comment: I added an example and the results + the link to the original XAML file on GitHub.

Comment: Alright, I reverted Xamarin.Forms back one Version to 4.1.0.581479. Here the issue does not occur. So it seems to be an issue with the latest release. Although I struggle to create an minimal reproduction example..

Comment: Open an issue on the Xamarin.Forms github repo, they will fix it.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as I'm able to create an reproduction example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout)** to realize it.Here is a sample code as bellow:

```
<RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Accent" >
    <Button Text="111" 
            HeightRequest="50" 
            WidthRequest="380" 
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0, Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0,Constant=50}"/>
    <Image Source="icon.png"
            HeightRequest="50" 
            WidthRequest="50"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.4, Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0,Constant=50}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems my issue lies with the wrapping ScrollViewer. I have updated my original post.

Comment: @NPadrutt Hi, if just happen in android , should be an issue. You can submit here https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox/issues .

Comment: Thanks, but that is my repository. So I would just report it to myself :) But it seems the issue is with the latest version of Xamarin Forms. I reverted back to 4.1.0.581479 and that solved it for  the moment.

Comment: @NPadrutt Okey , good idea . Later Forms will fixed this issue .

Answer (score 0):

you were close, you just have to put the `Label` after the `Button` int the xaml hierarchy:

```
    <Grid HeightRequest="60" VerticalOptions="Start">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

        <Label
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="15,0"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
            Foo
        </Label>

        <Image
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            HeightRequest="30"
            Source="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/6447-200.png"
            WidthRequest="30" />
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems my issue lies with the wrapping ScrollViewer. I have updated my original post.